# unable to pass the price range slider value through GET method on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I Want to create a filter option for the package on my website using noUiSlider script and PHP, but i am not able to pass or send the slider value from the form to process the data and filter it.

here is the HTML form

```
<div class="planfinder-form clearfix">
    <form  method="GET" action="search.php">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center col-md-12">
                <label for="price">
                    Price
                </label>
                <div >
                  <div  class ="slider" id="slider">
                    <input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="slider" value="" 
        min="0" max="2000">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-button form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-
   12 align-center" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 50px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search" value="search" />
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning find-plan">
                    <i class="flaticon-search">
                    </i>
                   Find  the Packages
                </button>
                <img id="loader_img" style="width: 40px; margin-left: 11px; display:none;" src="data/template/images/loader.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this is the JavaScript

```
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [0, 2000],
        connect: true,
        range: {
            'min': 0,
            '25%': 500,
            '50%': 1000,
            '75%': 1500,
            'max': 2000,
        },
        pips: {
            mode: 'range',
            density: 4,
            values: 5
        },
        tooltips: true,

    });
    $('.planfinder-types ul a').click(function(){
        var its_text = $(this).text();
        its_text = its_text.replace(/\s/g, '');
        if(its_text == 'MiFi/Dongles' || its_text == 'Data'){
           slider.noUiSlider.destroy();
           noUiSlider.create(slider, {
            start: [0, 7000],
            connect: true,
            range: {
                'min': 0,
                '25%': 1000,
                '50%': 2000,
                '75%': 5000,
                'max': 7000,
            },
            pips: {
                mode: 'range',
                density: 4,
                values: 5
            },
            tooltips: true,
        });

        }else{
            slider.noUiSlider.destroy();
            noUiSlider.create(slider, {
                start: [0, 2000],
                connect: true,
                range: {
                    'min': 0,
                    '25%': 500,
                    '50%': 1000,
                    '75%': 1500,
                    'max': 2000,
                },
                pips: {
                    mode: 'range',
                    density: 4,
                    values: 5
                },
                tooltips: true,
            });
```

and this is the submit header result that i get from it

http://localhost/package/search.php?price%5B%5D=&search=search

thanks in Advance

Comment: Where are you sending the value? There's no form submit and there's no ajax

Comment: There is form (  <form  method="GET" action="search.php">) and Ajax is included